# Trying to get my bootstrap row to even out with one column having two rows nested inside

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a wordpress site that is integrated with bootstrap and trying to do a "featured posts" type layout at the top of the blog to showcase or most recent blog posts. The problem I have having is that its one big row and half of the row is one big featured image and the other have is two rows nested inside. However I want them to always line-up as far as height. What I want it to look like:

[image]

and what it's looking like:

[image]

Everything online I've read says to put a container div around the left jumbo photo and give it the required height and width and also a overflow: hidden and the the actual `<img>` a width of 100% but it's not working for me. Not sure if this is right and some of my previous styling is messing this up or if I need to be doing something else.

So "big-photo" is the div I put around the `<img>` tag. I found another solution online that used a scale class(on my img tag) that I tried which also didn't work.

```
    <div class="latest-blogs">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="blog-box">
                <div class="big-photo">
                    <img class="featured-image scale" src="<?php echo $posts[0][3]; ?>" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="blog-infor">
                    <date><?php echo $posts[0][4]; ?></date>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php echo $posts[0][2]; ?>">
                            <?php echo $posts[0][1]; ?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $posts[0][5]; ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i < count($posts); $i++) : ?>
                <div class="blog-box">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="<?php echo $posts[$i][3]; ?>" alt="" />
                    <div class="blog-infor">
                        <date><?php echo $posts[$i][4]; ?></date>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="<?php echo $posts[$i][2]; ?>">
                                <?php echo $posts[$i][1]; ?>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <span>
                            <?php echo $posts[$i][5]; ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    .big-photo {
    max-height: 499px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.big-photo img {
    width: 100%;
}

.big-photo img.scale {
    /* corrects small inline gap at bottom of containing div */
display: block;
width: 100%; /* corrects obscure Firefox bug */
max-width: 100%;
/* just in case, to force correct aspect ratio */
height: auto !important;
display: block; /* corrects small inline gap at bottom of containing div */
width: 100% /* corrects obscure Firefox bug */
max-width: 100%;
/* just in case, to force correct aspect ratio */
height: auto !important;
/*width: auto\9;
/* ie8+9 - use modernizr instead of this \9 hack */
/* lt ie8 */
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
/* optionally force a minimum size if img src size is known: */
/* min-height: 320px; /* max-height of .crop-height */
/* min-width: 480px; /* proportional to above */ }
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: added in my php and css into my post

Comment: not enough,also check the class `.big-photo`,you have set the `max-height`.It might causing that.

Comment: the max-height is what I set on purpose in order to have it stretch and match the other column with two rows. Maybe I will start again from scratch. Thanks

Comment: the code you posted is not enough anyway

Comment: not enough for what? not enough for you to help me or not enough to fix the problem I am having? The php is the shortcode for that entire top section and the css is what I used for the bigger image to try and stretch. Im just trying to get the bigger image to match the 2 row column in height at all times. Is there any suggestions you can give me?

Comment: Is it possible to get a link to your page as well?  Might be able to better see what's going on with the page rendered.  I have a few suggestions, but would like to see the page itself to be able to offer a valid response.

Comment: Hey @DanielC I was able to figure out. My solution was working, I just had some other css over riding my changes. Thanks